Pyspark drop duplicates keep the non null row
Hi I have a dataset like this :



id
name




1
A


1
null


2
A


3
B


4
null


4
B


5
A


6
null



And I want to remove duplicates row and keep the row where the name is not null
This is the expected output



id
name




1
A


2
A


3
B


4
B


5
A


6
null



I tried this :
df
.orderBy("name", ascending=False)
.dropDuplicates(["id"])
.show(10, False)

It remove the duplicates rows but I get null values in the "name" column
Thanks in advance for helping

You can add filter to get not null values after dropDuplicates

Yes but for some IDs like the "6" I just have 1 row with null name and I don't want to remove this line because it's not a duplicate row

from pyspark.sql.functions import col, count, lit
schema_list = ['id','name']
data_list = [(1,'A'),(1,'null'),(2,'A'),(3,'B'),(4,'null'),(4,'B'),(5,'A'),(6,'null')]
Create the data frame
df = spark.createDataFrame(data_list,schema_list)
Create dataframe with ids which appear more than once
df_mult_id = df.groupBy('id').agg(count('name').alias('count')).filter(col('count')>1).select('id')
Create dataframe with ids which have name as null
df_null = df.filter(col('name')=='null').select('id')
Find common id between above both and putting null in name column
mult_null = df_null.intersect(df_mult_id).withColumn('name',lit('null'))
Subtract from original dataframe to get result
result = df.subtract(mult_null)
result.orderBy('id').show(20,False)
